# @mui/material with React 18 not working: export 'useContext' (imported as 'useContext') was not found in 'react'

Tags: reactjs, webpack, material-ui

When using @mui/material with React 18.1.0 and React-Dom 18.1.0, I'm getting a series of compatibility issues between emotion and react. This is odd because I do in fact have the latest version of react installed, so I'm not entirely sure what would be causing this.

```
WARNING in ./node_modules/@emotion/react/dist/emotion-element-cbed451f.browser.esm.js 12:41-54

export 'createContext' (imported as 'createContext') was not found in 'react' (possible exports: CacheProvider, ClassNames, Global, ThemeContext, ThemeProvider, __unsafe_useEmotionCache, createElement, css, jsx, keyframes, useTheme, withEmotionCache, withTheme)


WARNING in ./node_modules/@emotion/react/dist/emotion-element-cbed451f.browser.esm.js 28:9-19

export 'useContext' (imported as 'useContext') was not found in 'react' (possible exports: CacheProvider, ClassNames, Global, ThemeContext, ThemeProvider, __unsafe_useEmotionCache, createElement, css, jsx, keyframes, useTheme, withEmotionCache, withTheme)
```

On the javascript console, I'm seeing:

```
root.js:3049 Uncaught TypeError: (0 , react__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_5__.createContext) is not a function
    at eval (emotion-element-cbed451f.browser.esm.js?c3e7:12:55)
    at Module../node_modules/@emotion/react/dist/emotion-element-cbed451f.browser.esm.js (root.js:74:1)
```

These are the versions of I'm using

```
"@emotion/react": "^11.9.0",
"@emotion/styled": "^11.8.1",
"@mui/icons-material": "^5.8.0",
"@mui/material": "^5.8.1",
"react": "^18.1.0",
"react-dom": "^18.1.0",
"react-redux": "^8.0.2",
"react-router": "^6.3.0",
"react-router-dom": "^6.3.0",
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This error has happened to me several times when using this library with Webpack.

This error happens because the library is inside a folder with the same name as react's library.

To fix this issue, you need to add a custom alias to your Webpack's config:

```
resolve: {
    alias: {
        react: Path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules/react')
    },
    [rest of you config]
}
```

Comment: This fixed it for us, too, using React 17 and webpack 5, with emotion. But obviously it's not happening to many people, so I'm left wondering what is special about our webpack setup that could cause this? It seems like a unexpected behavior for webpack to choose a parent directory like that.