# NextJS latest can't deploy for an error "Named export 'useContext' not found"

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, next.js

I am using the following package.json

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "@nextui-org/react": "^2.2.8",
    "axios": "^1.6.0",
    "framer-motion": "^10.16.4",
    "next": "latest",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^20",
    "@types/react": "^18",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.16",
    "eslint": "^8",
    "eslint-config-next": "14.0.0",
    "postcss": "^8.4.31",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.3.5",
    "typescript": "^5"
  }
}
```

To be able to deploy my NextJS application in the cloud, using the docker-file of this [link](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/canary/examples/with-docker-multi-env/docker/production/Dockerfile).

However, when I enter my deployed application it gives me an Internal Server Error, and when I see the logs it gives me the following:

```
import $73SJx$react, {useContext as $73SJx$useContext, useState as $73SJx$useState, useMemo as $73SJx$useMemo, useLayoutEffect as $73SJx$useLayoutEffect, useRef as $73SJx$useRef} from "react";
```

```
SyntaxError: Named export 'useContext' not found. The requested module 'react' is a CommonJS module, which may not support all module.exports as named exports.
```

I haven't been able to solve it so far. Is there something I need to configure or change the version?

```
I hope to be able to deploy my application in the cloud with the correct configurations
```

Comment: As the error states that `use context is not found` and this requested module react is not supported for all module.exports as named exports. So, can you try to upgrade your React version to 18.2.0 and try again. . By referring to this [official doc](https://react.dev/reference/react/useContext) make sure to give the valid syntax as "const value = useContext(SomeContext)".

Comment: @HemanthKumar So, my package.json is not correct? Any necessary changes should I make?

Comment: Can you have a check on this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73262278/19230181) by Tim Mouskhelichvili and try by adding this in your deploy.

Comment: Please let me know whether the shared info was helpful. I am happy to assist if you have any further queries.

Comment: @HemanthKumar your answer and references could give me the path to the solution. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error states that use context is not found and this requested module react is not supported for all module.exports as named exports. So, can you try to upgrade your React version to 18.2.0 and try again. . By referring to this [official doc](https://react.dev/reference/react/useContext) make sure to give the valid syntax as `"const value = useContext(SomeContext)"`. To make the necessary changes in the package.json  refer to this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73262278/19230181) by Tim Mouskhelichvili and try by adding this in your deploy.